# Es6 Fetch/Promise Context

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

In the browser, I'm trying to use ES6 promise, and ES6 fetch, with Reflux.js actions, but i'm having trouble binding the context of 'this' within a anonymous arrow function. What am I doing wrong?

*** Update *** 
I'm using Reflux.js ListenAndPromise, I probably should have added this in my orignal question

*** Update ***

Got the context working when I remove the outer arrow function 
This works:

```html
CrewActions.fetchCrew.listenAndPromise(function() {
  fetch('crew.json')
  .then(function() {
    console.log(this);  // This is bound as expected 
  }.bind(this))
});
```

But This does not work

```js
CrewActions.fetchCrew.listenAndPromise(function() {
  fetch('crew.json')
  .then(() => {
    console.log(this);  // undefined 
  })
});
```

So I guess I'm mistaken on how arrow functions work?  I thought they bound the context of this?

None of the below examples work.

Example.

```js
CrewActions.fetchCrew.listenAndPromise(() => {

  console.log(this)
    // functor() {
    //    var triggerType = functor.sync ? "trigger" : "triggerAsync";
    //    return functor[triggerType].apply(functor, arguments);
    // }

  fetch('crew.json')
    .then(_.bind(() => {
      console.log(this) // undefined 
    }, this))


  fetch('crew.json')
    .then(() => console.log(this)); // undefined 

  fetch('crew.json')
    .then(function() {
      console.log(this) // undefined
    });


  fetch('crew.json')
    .then(function() {
      console.log(this) // undefined
    }.bind(this));
});
```

Comment: In the first case, you can't bind Arrow Functions. For the rest, what is "this" defined as in the first place?  The last example should work, try 
.then(function() { console.log(this)}.bind({jellybeans:true})) and it should log the jellybeans object.

Comment: node or the browser? please provide a [mcve]

Comment: are these calls made on the global context or within an object instance?

Comment: Called in browser, in another anonymous arrow function

Comment: So, I'm not getting anything in the console when I run that snippet, since the outer arrow function is never run. You could make it like an IIFE using `(()=>{})()`. When I do that with your code, I get the `window` object for the last three. The first one is never called, most likely because, as @Dtipson mentioned, you can't bind arrow functions.

Comment: a simple way of handing `this` to arrows: https://gist.github.com/rndme/8b2b72ec2fb461884942 also, you can't bind() arrows like other functions. in short, use an old-fashioned function on the outside, and you can set `this` in there for all the arrows.

Comment: What is supposed to be `this`? if you are executing this in the global context, `this` is expected to be `undefined`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. That `console.log(this)` that logs an object can't be right - all evidence (of the callbacks) points against it. Are you sure these are in the same scope?

Comment: @dandavis in this case, it's being bound to the same `this` as the arrow function would have? @GastonSanchez `this` from the global context is the global object.

Comment: "*So I guess I'm mistaken on how arrow functions work?*" - No, this is indeed how they should work. There either is some bug in the implementation (transpiler? ES6 environment?) or there is additional code that influences this.

Comment: @JuanMendes: yes, the arrows have/keep whatever `this` is in-play when the functions are defined.  basically, in arrows, `this` is un-alterable and setup at the same time as closure-reachable variables, instead of at call time like in "normal" functions.

Comment: @dandavis I understand arrow functions, I just don't understand what your suggestion would fix. The OP is showing an example where they are using arrow functions that should work. The question is why isn't that working.

Comment: my suggestion is to use an outer function to make `this` for the arrows dynamic. but now that it's edited, i see a different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try a simplified version of the Arrow function version of that:

```
function listenAndPromise() {
 console.log('outer fn',this);
  return fetch('crew.json')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('arrowfn',this);  // undefined
  })
}
listenAndPromise.bind({test:4})();
```

It logs, outer fn Object {test: 4} then arrowfn Object {test: 4}

That's what I would expect. The outer function is given a this context, and the arrow function doesn't add new "this" context/meaning. Your results may have more to do with your environment (or what CrewActions.fetchCrew.listenAndPromise has bound "this" to) than the internal functions themselves.